# Clarify glFrustum, and why I can't see the image

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, dimension

currently I have my glFrustum set as

```
glFrustum(0, 100.0, 0, 100.0, -50, 50);
```

And my image is a rectangular cube, with dimensions :
Why can't I see the image, when the dimension of the shape is smaller than the viewing box?

```
//top
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(25, 60, 25);
        glVertex3f(75, 60, 25);
        glVertex3f(75, 60, -25);
        glVertex3f(25, 60, -25);
    glEnd();

    //bottom
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(25, 55, 25);
        glVertex3f(75, 55, 25);
        glVertex3f(75, 55, -25);
        glVertex3f(25, 55, -25);
    glEnd();

    //front
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(25, 55, 25);
        glVertex3f(75, 55, 25);
        glVertex3f(75, 60, 25);
        glVertex3f(25, 60, 25);
    glEnd();

    //back
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(25, 60, -25);
        glVertex3f(75, 60, -25);
        glVertex3f(75, 55, -25);
        glVertex3f(25, 55, -25);
    glEnd();
```

Comment: Reto Koradi already gave you a good answer. If you have problems picturing how the frustum works, you may want to have a look at this: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum/frustum.c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments of this `glFrustum()` call are invalid:

```
glFrustum(0, 100.0, 0, 100.0, -50, 50);
```

The `nearVal`, which is the 5th parameter, must be positive. From the [man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml):

> nearVal, farVal: Specify the distances to the near and far depth clipping planes. Both distances must be positive.

Picture these as distances from the camera, in the direction it is pointing. A value of -50.0 would put the near clipping plane behind the camera, which is invalid.

To get this to work, while keeping the same range, you could change this to for example:

```
glFrustum(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 50.0, 150.0);
```

Without any additional transformations, the camera points from the origin down the negative z-axis. Since we shifted the near and far distance by 100.0 compared to the original code, you need to shift the object accordingly, which corresponds to a translation of -100.0 in the z-direction. To do this, you can either modify the coordinates of your vertices, or apply a transformation as part of the modelview transformation:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
// draw calls
glPopMatrix();
```

Also note that the first 4 parameters of your `glFrustum()` call are somewhat unconventional. They specify a non-symmetric frustum. The result will look like the camera is placed above a corner of your window. While this is perfectly legal, it will probably look odd. It's much more common to have a symmetric frustum, which means that left/right and top/bottom have the same absolute value each, with opposite signs. For example:

```
glFrustum(-50.0, 50.0, -50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 150.0);
```

To match this, you will want to place the x/y coordinates of your geometry around the origin.